# SQL - How to set a constraint on ALL columns but one efficiently?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, triggers, sqlplus, check-constraints

Using SQL Plus, I am attempting to set a trigger that would prevent anyone from updating a table unless it's **one** specific column. It doesn't have to be necessarily a trigger.

Say in a table of 6 columns, you want to only allow the users to update c3 and disallow any other changes.

My solution to the above example is to do the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T1_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE OF c1,c2,c4,c5,c6 ON t1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20121, 'ERROR -> You can only update C3');
END;
```

I was wondering if this can be done in a manner that is more efficient without having to specify every other columns. The issue that I see in this is that if I ever modify the tables for additional columns later on, this constraint would need to be adjusted everytime.

Comment: Which database are you using?  MySQL and SQLite are not the same thing.

Comment: SQL Plus Oracle Database 11!

Comment: Why is updating the trigger if/when the table structure changes a problem? Surely that’s just part of the cost of ongoing development?